# Excel VBA PasteSpecial Transpose:=True Posts only the last value in range

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code which will find all the values in column B where Column A matches the declared value ThisCell.   I know there are about 15 matching values.  When I try to paste these values in the cells to the right of ThisCell using this code

```
For i = 4 To Finalrow
If Cells(i, 1) = ThisCell Then
Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Copy
ThisCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True


End If
```

I only get the last value in the cell to the right of This Cell.  I see the cell updating through all the values. When I add an resize argument like this
ThisCell.Offset(0, 1).resize(,20).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True I get 20 cells filled with the last value.   Any idea how to write the ThisCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True so I get all the values?

Answer (score 0):

I should have thought of this first--the problem was with how I wrote the the Thiscell.offset line.   Using the cells method I rewrote the code as

```
  Cells(ThisCell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial 
  _ Transpose:=True
```

And that worked like a charm.